# How to get Event Hub-compatible endpoint connection string using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, endpoint, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub, azure-cli

I am trying to get the connection string of 'Event Hub-compatible endpoint' present in the iot hub using Azure CLI. Is there any command to get the connection string information?

Comment: I think we should add `EventHubConnectionStringIsInvalid` to the title to help find this question and its accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can get the eventhub-compatible connection string of an IoT Hub with the following command:

```
az iot hub connection-string show -n <IoT Hub name> --default-eventhub
```

Do note that this reference is part of the [azure-iot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-iot/?view=azure-cli-latest) extension for Azure CLI and requires version **2.0.70** or higher.

As elaborated by @Stefan below:

One thing to note is that by default this command returns the connection string for the `iothubowner` policy. Use the `--policy-name` parameter to specify the shared access policy explicitly, for example:

```
az iot hub connection-string show -n <IoT Hub name> --default-eventhub --policy-name service
```

Comment: One thing to note is that by default this command returns the connection string for the 'iothubowner' policy. Use the '--policy-name' parameter to specify the shared access policy explicitly, for example 'az iot hub connection-string show -n <IoT Hub name> --default-eventhub --policy-name service'

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Thank you for the insights. I've edited my post to include this info as well. :)